# Angular not updating contents of ng-paginate when collection changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have a collection that i am displaying on view using ng-paginate::
    "....tr dir-paginate="item in data.gridData ..."

I give users an ability to edit an items' properties (item's status) using a modal. Once I save status, I fetch updated grid data from backend and bind back     like so: 
    $scope.getData = function (id) {
        applicationService.getData(id)
           .then(
           function (data) {

```
           $scope.data.gridData.length = 0;
           data.data.forEach(function (item) { $scope.data.gridData.push(item) });
           $scope.$digest();
           $scope.$apply();

       });
```

The problem is the status DOES NOT change for the updated item. I made sure that correct status is saved and then retrieved from DB. I tried everything I could find, including, as you can see, setting collection length to 0, calling digest, apply, etc. Nothing. It is like the data is "stuck". It is only refreshed when I navigate away/back to page. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using track by.

```
<div ng-repeat="value in [4, 4] track by $index"></div>
```